# Why does my soap response return just the first elements when I print_r the results of the call

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I have created a non-wsdl call to a soap service. The `_getLastResponse()` returns the expected response, but when I `print_r($result)`, I just get the first node.

To see the test page with the response go to :http://primevaluationservices.com/myriad/test.php

Below is my code:

```
$p = new StdClass();
$p->MDHeader =  new StdClass(); 
$p->MDHeader->userid = "inspector@prime.com";
$p->MDHeader->password = "prime123456";
$p->RECORDSET =  new StdClass(); 
$p->RECORDSET->row->id = "0";

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' =>   "https://uat.myriadexchange.com/isocket/listUserInspections/",
                                 'uri'      => "https://uat.myriadexchange.com/isocket/listUserInspections/",
                                 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                 'features' => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE,
                                 'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
                                 'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                                 'trace'    => 1,
                                 'exceptions'=> 0));


$result = $client->_soapCall('test',$p);
echo("<br>Dumping request headers:<br>"  .$client->__getLastRequestHeaders()."<br>");
echo "<hr>";
echo("<b>Dumping request XML:<br>".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest())."<br>");
echo "<hr>";
echo("<br>Dumping response headers:<br>".$client->__getLastResponseHeaders()."<br>");  
echo "<hr>";
echo("<br>Dumping response XML:<br>".htmlspecialchars(urldecode($client->__getLastResponse()))."<br>");
echo "<hr>";
echo("<br>Dumping response record:<br>");
print_r($result);
```

This is the result of my `print_r($result)`

`Array ( [userid] => inspector@prime.com [password] => prime123456 [batchid] => 1234 )`

This is the result of `_getLastResponse()`

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><MDHeader><userid>inspector@prime.com</userid><password>prime123456</password><batchid>1234</batchid></MDHeader><RECORDSET><ROW id='0'>%3CINSPECTIONS%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835410936%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835221706%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222299%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222333%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222368%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222426%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222460%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222495%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222520%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222553%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222587%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222622%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222647%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222680%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222714%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222749%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222774%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835222807%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835223569%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835223536%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835223603%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835224239%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3CFOLDER_ID%3E835353387%3C%2FFOLDER_ID%3E%3C%2FINSPECTIONS%3E</ROW></RECORDSET></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "test" service just echoes back the XML sent.  And it looks like the XML sent has 2 root elements, `MDHeader` and `RECORDSET`.  I believe a SOAP request and response should have just 1 root element.  Looks like instead of failing on receiving 2 root elements, `_soapCall` is forgiving enough that it returns a result containing just the 1st root element and its descendants.  Try this:

```
$p = new StdClass();
$p->MDHeader =  new StdClass(); 
$p->MDHeader->userid = "inspector@prime.com";
$p->MDHeader->password = "prime123456";
$p->MDHeader->RECORDSET =  new StdClass(); 
$p->MDHeader->RECORDSET->row->id = "0";
```

This way, everything will be under 1 root element, `MDHeader`.

Comment: There is no question that the request and response being sent back is correct. I have verified that with the vendor. It is the array that is displayed with print_r that is incorrect.